# How to check the platforms a package is supported?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

When I tried to install a package to a UWP project, it gave this error:

```
Install-Package : Package QuickFix.Net 1.7.0 is not compatible with uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0). Package QuickFix.Net 1.7.0 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
At line:1 char:1
```

But nothing on the package page indicts that it cannot be used with uwp, how can I check that what platforms a given package is supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content on package page provided by the package author. So if the author doesn't statement what platform the package doesn't support, there will not have such content on package page. But author often statement what platform the package supports.

For example, following statement query on QuickFix.NET package means this package is used for .NET platform development. So the UWP app which used UAP platform could not use this .NET platform package.

> QuickFIX/n attempts to keep the same robustness and conformance of
>   QuickFIX with a similar API while bringing native performance and
>   idiomatic **usage to .NET**.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something in the metadata. I don't think every packages' description contains such information.

Comment: @fluter The supported platform information is not listed in metadata. You could open a package with NuGet Package Explorer to view the metadata, there are some basic information, such as package Id, version, authors, copyright, description, dependencies and so on, which not contains supported platform.

Comment: @Wendy-MSFT I see the new nuget.org preview doesn't indicate supported platforms in any way either. That's really disappointing - it's one of the most fundamental things I want to know about a package, and it's all there in the metadata. Do you know if the team is considering something like this? Simply listing the subfolder names under /lib in the unzipped package would be a great start.